# LESS, can hover code be written differently?

Tags: css, less

I have been working on LESS for quite some time and am quite familiar with it. But I have been fiddling around to see the extent of what LESS can do.

```
.col-three{
  padding: 20px 0;
  height: 640px;

  aside{
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;

    .text{
      .fsize(43px);
      color: @white;
      .bold;
      .uppercase;
      position: absolute;
      top:50%; 
      left: 50%;
      .centerposition;
      word-spacing: 9999999px;
      .alcenter;

      span {
        background: rgba(184,181,175,0.8);
        line-height: 140%;
        .transition();
      }
    }
  }

  &:nth-child(2){
    padding: 0;

    aside {
      .text {
        .fsize(62px);
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }

  &:hover{
    aside > .text > span {
      color:@black
    }
  }
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine, what it does is when I hover to the `.col-three` the `span` inside the `.text` changes color to black. Works Perfectly fine. But my question is however is it possible to write this code

```
  &:hover{
    aside > .text > span {color:@black}
  }
```

in any different way so that I don't have to point to all the child elements of `.col-three` to reach the `span`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In LESS we can do code like php and same code we can loop in multiple classes by using @ .you can use '>' tag.

Comment: @PrajwalShrestha can you please explain in detail?? isn't @ used to define variables???

Comment: @abizit: Less selectors are nothing but CSS selectors. Check with your HTML if you can write `.col-three:hover span` as the selector and if you can then you can do the same in Less also. If you can't (that is say for example there is another `span` outside `.text` which is also getting styled) then you can't do it with Less also. (*Note:* Please format the code better before posting. It helps readability.)

Comment: maybe its not the real good way, but why don't you create another small class and add it to your element. in this way you can reach your element with `&:hover { & .class1 {} }`

Answer (score 1):

If you can have a selector wrapper for hover...

```
<div class="hover-wrapper">
   <div class="col-threee">
      ...original hierarchy...
   </div>
</div>
```

You can use...

```
.col-three{
  ...

  aside {
    ...

    > .text {
      ...

      > span {
         ...
         .hover-wrapper:hover & {
            color:black;
         }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```